# ClientQueryString returns "nDev%3d6%3b" but I was expecting "nDev=6;"

Tags: asp.net, .net

string strTemp=this.ClientQueryString

got me "nCon%3d5%3bnDev%3d6%3bWu%3d15%3blw%3d400%3biw%3d100%3b"
but I was expecting to parse for "nCon=5;nDev=6;Wu=15;lw=400;iw=100;"
Probably not using ClientQueryString the way it should be used

```
   // making up my own client query string format is
   // ?url=xxx;nDev=n;nCon=n;Wu=n;lw=n;iw=n;
   bool DoPreset(string strId, string strIn, ref TextBox MyTb)
    {
    int iStart, iTerm, iSize = strId.Length;
    iStart = strIn.IndexOf(strId);
    if (iStart < 0) return false;
    iTerm = strIn.IndexOf(";", iStart);
    if (iTerm <= 0) return false;
    iStart += iSize;
    iSize = iTerm - iStart;
    if (iSize <= 0) return false;
    MyTb.Text = strIn.Substring(iStart, iSize);
    return true;
    }
    bool HavePreset(string strIn)
    {
    if(strIn == "") return false;
    DoPreset("nCon=", strIn, ref tb_ntasks);
    DoPreset("nDev=", strIn, ref tb_ngpu);
    DoPreset("Wu=", strIn, ref tb_num2read);
    DoPreset("lw=", strIn, ref tb_watts);
    DoPreset("iw=", strIn, ref tb_idle);
    return DoPreset("ProjUrl=", strIn, ref ProjUrl);
    }
…
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if(!HavePreset(this.ClientQueryString))
                ProjUrl.Text = ddlTest.SelectedValue;
            }
…
```

Expected to extract the values between the equal sign and the semicolon but got the ascii value of the equal and the semicolon

Comment: Are you decoding at all?

Comment: Either I am decoding too much or I am not coding at all and I suspect I am not coding it up correctly at all.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I looked at that api.  No example was given but in any event my VS2017 stops somewhere at dotnet 4.6 and that urldecode is 4.8 I fixed the problem by substituting %3b for ; and %3d for =  but probably a more elegant way to do it as I think of this as a hack.

Comment: If you read that documentation, it tells you exactly what to do.  You just need to do something like ````string myString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(this.ClientQueryString)````

Comment: And for future reference, just looking for code examples is not going to be ample enough. I know it's nice when someone tells you what to do, but half of the learning process is to read documentation (like the Microsoft Docs) and then test the code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your data looks to be url encoded. You could add this line at the beginning of your method...

```
strIn = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(strIn);
```

Also, make sure you have the System.Web namespace.

For more details check out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You are correct.  I figured that out just before you posted.  I assume my solution is OK.

Comment: Glad to hear it!